# Not getting an output of the OpenCV program in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run this program in jupyter notebook, but it's not running at all. It's just showing the asterisk beside the program. Can anyone tell me why is that happening? I have also tried other programs of OpenCV as well, but the result was the same. None of them are running.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
image = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  
cv2.imshow('Original image',image)
cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)
  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The import statements should be on separate lines. I.e. line1:`import cv2`, line2: `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code, opencv `imshow` cause issues with notebook.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

plt.imshow(gray)
plt.title('Gray image')
plt.show()
```